# Critical points of $f(x, y, z) = \frac{x^5 + y^5+z^5}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

What are the critical points of $f(x, y, z) = \dfrac{x^5 + y^5+z^5}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$?

I get a complicated system of equations which is not linear that I do not know how to solve when I equal the gradient vector to $(0, 0, 0)$. Is there a general approach to this type of problems?

Comment: is $(0,0,0)$ really a solution?

Comment: OP didn't say $(0,0,0)$ was a solution. @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the function in 5-dimensional polar coordinates, so that $f(r,\omega) = r^3 F(\omega)$ for some $F(\omega)$ on the 4-dimensional unit sphere.

First of all, notice the origin is a critical point since all outward directional derivatives there are zero. (This case can also be done readily from the definition.) At any other critical point, the radial derivative has to be zero, so you would have to have $F(\omega) = 0$ there, which is the same as saying $x^5 + y^5 + z^5 = 0$.

Next, note that if $(x,y,z) \neq (0,0,0)$, then $\partial_x f(x,y,z)$ is given by
$$\partial_x f(x,y,z) = (x^5 + y^5 + z^5) \, \partial_x \bigg({1 \over x^2 + y^2 + z^2}\bigg) + 5x^4 \bigg({1 \over x^2 + y^2 + z^2}\bigg)$$
If $x^5 + y^5 + z^5 = 0$ then this becomes
$$\partial_x f(x,y,z) =  5x^4 \bigg({1 \over x^2 + y^2 + z^2}\bigg)$$
So if $\partial_x f(x,y,z) = 0$ one must have $x = 0$. Similarly, $x^5 + y^5 + z^5 = 0$ and $\partial_y f(x,y,z) = 0$ imply that $y = 0$ and $x^5 + y^5 + z^5 = 0$ and $\partial_z f(x,y,z) = 0$ imply that $z = 0$. Thus at any critical point other than the origin, one must have $x = y = z = 0$, which never happens. Thus the origin is the only critical point.